# I'm having an issue with this PHP browser-specific alert

Tags: php, javascript

Im currently coding a design tutorial site for developers and I have a snippet of code that basically throws a small alert on the page if the end-user is using an outdated version of IE on the screen.

As useless as it sounds, it's what the client wants. Oh well.

Basically, I can't get the damn this to close when you click the "Close this box" link. Here is the code. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

// IE6,7,8 string from user_agent
$ie6 = "MSIE 6.0";
$ie7 = "MSIE 7.0";
$ie8 = "MSIE 8.0";

// detect browser
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

// yank the version from the string
$browser = substr("$browser", 25, 8);

// html for error
$error = "<div class=\"error\" id=\"error\"><strong>Alert:</strong> It appears that you    
are using Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.  While you may still visit this website we 
encourage you to upgrade your web browser so you can enjoy all the rich features this 
website offers as well as other websites. Follow this link to <a 
href=\"http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/ie/getitnow.mspx\"><strong>Upgrade 
your Internet Explorer</strong></a><br /><div class=\"kickRight\"><a href=\"javascript: 
killIt('error');\"> Close This Box</a></div></div>";

// if IE6 set the $alert 
if($browser == $ie6){ $alert = TRUE; }
if($browser == $ie7){ $alert = TRUE; }
if($browser == $ie8){ $alert = TRUE; }

?>
```

And then you add this into the BODY wherever you may want it:

```
<!-- IE6 Detect Advise Notice -->
<?php if($alert){ echo $error; } ?>
<!-- // end IE6 Detect Advise Notice -->
```

I can't get the damn this to close. I don't know what the problem is. It may be the there is javascript trying to close a PHP error box. I don't know c-based languages so I don't know. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes, there's JavaScript involved here. The function name is `killIt`.

Comment: You should display the box using conditional comments instead of this fragile PHP mess.

Comment: I will research this. But this PHP box works fine I just can't get it to close. So if that is an easier fix, I'll just stick with that. the killIt() function isn't working. Im wondering if it's because that's a javascript command trying to kill a function formed in PHP....?

Answer (score 1):

Your close button is attempting to fire a JavaScript function called `killIt()` with a parameter of `'error'`. I'm going to guess that you haven't included that function on the page, or that there's an error in it.

Comment: I know there is a JS function here. But my question is "will a JS function kill a PHP function?" The original author of this code must have thought so...but how would I call the javascript function to kill this PHP code? Could I wrap the PHP in a JS function? as far as I know different languages cannot be nested within each other....

Comment: @MikeLegacy Once the page has been sent to a client, PHP no longer has its hands on anymore.  It's now client-side processing.  The PHP is merely creating an HTML document that the browser interprets.  So any PHP-specific errors that are generated are specific to the server and to be handled there.  There can be an illusion of PHP and JavaScript working in tandem at the same time, but that's only because of XmlHttpRequests.  The reality is, once it's on the client, the browser deals with it, until it contacts the server.  They're oblivious to PHP / JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the killIt javascript function to HTML. It would not remove any PHP code at server-side, but rather HTML output of PHP code in the browser. You haven't shown us the code for killIt, but my guess is that it either hides or removes the DIV that PHP prints.